# Get correct value from array in Hive QL

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, qubole

I have a Wrapped Array and want to only get the corresponding **value struct** when I query with **LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE**.

SAMPLE STRUCTURE:

**COLUMNNAME: theARRAY**

```
WrappedArray([null,theVal,valTags,[123,null,null,null,null,null],false], [null,theVar,varTags,[abc,null,null,null,null,null],false])
```

schema is

```
array<struct<id:string,name:string,type:string,value:struct<member0:string,member1:bigint,member2:int,member3:double,member4:float,member5:boolean>,shouldIndex:boolean>>
```

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT theName, allValues
FROM table 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(column.name) theTab1 AS theName
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(column.value.member0) theTab2 AS allValues
WHERE theName = 'theVal'
```

My result:

```
___________________________
|**theName**|**allValues**|
___________________________
|theVal     |     123     |
___________________________
| theVal    |     abc     |
___________________________
```

I need:

```
___________________________
|**theName**|**allValues**|
___________________________
|theVal     |     123     |
___________________________
```

How can fix my query to get the result as above?

Answer (score 0):

Your additional explode on top of the structure is not needed. You should be able to perform that like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT theName, column.value.member0
FROM table 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(column.name) theTab1 AS theName
WHERE theName = 'theVal'
```

Comment: Does the same thing. It returns all the results for **allValues**

Comment: it does not make sense.  can you print the select * from yourtable form hive? Also, run describe yourtable in hive and add the result.  if you explode a record with 1 element array, the result should be 1 record ...